# Why isn't my div position getting dynamically calculated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the jQuery:

```
$('img[title*=\"Show\"]').live('click', function(e) {
    //$e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();      
    var position = $('img[title*=\"Show\"]').parent().position();
    $('#popover').css('top', position.top + $('img[title*=\"Show\"]').parent().height());
    console.log(position);
    $('#popover').fadeToggle('fast');
    if ($('img[title*=\"Show\"]').hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('img[title*=\"Show\"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
```

I have two images titled "Show Options."

The popover div appears properly when I click on the first image.

When I click on the 2nd image, the popover appears underneath the first image.

I want it to appear underneath the 2nd image.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using offset instead of position

```
  $(this).parent().offset();
```

you will also have to use "this" instead of the ID as it will always match the first pic

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. Clicking on the 2nd image makes it appear underneath the first image.

Comment: Great! Almost there. Now there is a noticable height gap between the image the div. Any way to get them closer together so that they are maybe 5 px apart?

Comment: Changed to `position.top + $(this).height()` but still same gap

Comment: will all images have same height? then try adding the height manually, do images have any margin set? if yes then minus the margin from height

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the 3rd line to:

```
Var position = $(this).parent().position();
```

When your event handler is called $(this) will refer to the element that was clicked on.